# Querying pivoted table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data arrangement as below:
[image: sample data from sampletab table]

This is table 1. Table 2 data is as below:

[image]

By joining the above data, I want to query like below. The external ID should be  specific cvid and cid. For example,

```
1001*98564*2*2*5*1
1002*98564*5*6*2*1
1003*98565*2*2*2*2
1004*98566*1*6*5*2
```

Below is my query to pivot the table 1 data:

```
select cvid,cid, sum(case when question_text = 'text1' then extid else 0 end) as [a],
                  sum(case when question_text = 'text2' then extid else 0 end) as [b],
                  sum(case when question_text = 'text3' then extid else 0 end) as [c],
                  sum(case when question_text = 'text4' then extid else 0 end) as [d] 
from #sampletab
```

But unable to proceed beyond. Any suggesstions?

PS: The data and time in second table is of no use! Also I am not allowed to hardcode any IDs. However I have hardcoded the question text since I had no other option.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also, not sure what the expected output is...

Comment: If you add a `GROUP BY` to your pivot query, it should work as expected.  I'm unsure what the expected output is too.

Comment: @both - I want the output as mentioned above. Please read through the question fully!

Comment: @clinomaniac The expected output is the snippet with the values separated by asterisks. For Jiah...  that's not very clear. You have to read very carefully to figure that out. Rephrasing that section might get you some better answers. Also, re-entering your sample data as text rather than images will help.

Comment: Sassy response from someone asking for help.  I did read your question but the output is unclear.  Are those asterisks separating the data or do you want to multiply all the column values together?  Did you try adding a group by to your current pivot query I mentioned?  ie `GROUP BY cvid, cid`?

Answer (score 0):

We'll start here:

```
SELECT t2.cvid, t2.cid, t1a.extid, t1b.extid, t1c.extid, t1d.extid
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1a ON t1a.cvid = t2.cvid and t1a.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1a.qid = 11
INNER JOIN Table1 t1b ON t1b.cvit1bd = t2.cvid and t1b.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1b.qid = 21
INNER JOIN Table1 t1c ON t1c.cvid = t2.cvid and t1c.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1c.qid = 31
INNER JOIN Table1 t1d ON t1d.cvid = t2.cvid and t1d.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1d.qid = 41
```

This produces the results requested in the question, albeit by using hard-coded qid values. It can be simplified using conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT t2.cvid, t2.cid, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.qid = 11 THEN t1.extid ELSE 0 END) A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.qid = 21 THEN t1.extid ELSE 0 END) B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.qid = 31 THEN t1.extid ELSE 0 END) C,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.qid = 41 THEN t1.extid ELSE 0 END) D
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.cvid = t2.cvid and t1.cid = t2.cid
GROUP BY t2.cvid, t2.cid
```

This also matches what you were trying to do in the question with less code and probably better performance, but keep the first option in mind; we'll adapt it further in a bit.

---

> Also I am not allowed to hardcode any IDs.

Why not? A quirk of the SQL language is you **MUST** be able to know the number and types of the columns in the result set at compile time for the language. If you can have any number of unknown `qid` values, you will have no choice but to resort to doing this in two steps with dynamic SQL. Even when using the `PIVOT` keyword, you have to declare the columns for the result set.

If you *really* want to avoid using the `qid`/`quest`/`question_text` values, but still know the number of columns, we can go back to the first part of my answer and adapt it to use a map like this (hint: it's slower, and still requires the IDs be discrete and consistent):

```
WITH ID_Map As  (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER by qid) as RowKey, qid
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY qid
)
SELECT t2.cvid, t2.cid, t1a.extid, t1b.extid, t1c.extid, t1d.extid
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN ID_Map m1 ON m1.RowKey = 1
INNER JOIN Table1 t1a ON t1a.cvid = t2.cvid and t1a.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1a.qid = m1.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m2 ON m2.RowKey = 2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1b ON t1b.cvit1bd = t2.cvid and t1b.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1b.qid = m2.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m3 ON m3.RowKey = 3
INNER JOIN Table1 t1c ON t1c.cvid = t2.cvid and t1c.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1c.qid = m3.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m4 ON m4.RowKey = 4
INNER JOIN Table1 t1d ON t1d.cvid = t2.cvid and t1d.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1d.qid = m4.qid
```

The only advantage here is you don't need to know exactly what the `qid` values are. You only need to know there are four of them, and they are used consistently.

We can do a little better still by including the `cvid` and `cid` values in our map:

```
WITH ID_Map As  (
    SELECT cvid, cid, qid, row_number() over (PARTITION BY cvid, cid ORDER by qid) as RowKey
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT t2.cvid, t2.cid, t1a.extid, t1b.extid, t1c.extid, t1d.extid
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN ID_Map m1 ON m1.cvid = t2.cvid and m1.cid = t2.cid
    AND m1.RowKey = 1
INNER JOIN Table1 t1a ON t1a.cvid = t2.cvid and t1a.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1a.qid = m1.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m2 ON m2.cvid = t2.cvid and m2.cid = t2.cid
    AND m2.RowKey = 2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1b ON t1b.cvit1bd = t2.cvid and t1b.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1b.qid = m2.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m3 ON m3.cvid = t2.cvid and m3.cid = t2.cid 
    AND m3.RowKey = 3
INNER JOIN Table1 t1c ON t1c.cvid = t2.cvid and t1c.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1c.qid = m3.qid
INNER JOIN ID_Map m4 ON m4.cvid = t2.cvid and m4.cid = t2.cid 
    AND m4.RowKey = 4
INNER JOIN Table1 t1d ON t1d.cvid = t2.cvid and t1d.cid = t2.cid
    AND t1d.qid = m4.qid
```

And now the codes no longer need to be used consistently between questions. It's enough to know that a question has for codes... though this is still a hard requirement. Remember, the SQL language requires that you **MUST** have a known set of result columns. You can improve this a little further by using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in a few places, and this way potentially have `NULL` values for some of the columns in your results, rather than removing the records entirely. I leave that as an exercise.

As a final note, conventional wisdom is you are really much better off pivoting this data on the *client program*, after you have retrieved it from the database.